# Keyboard Control Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keyboard

I want python to click <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, I don't want to install any outside extensions. I want it to click enter without using them. I found many resources like win32 but I want to do it without using external resources. I don't mind which version of python it is on.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how?

I have looked on the web but couldn't find anything. Please, can someone help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. It should definitely be possible using the ctypes library to talk directly to the Windows dlls

If you don't want to install a helper module that has done all this for you, then you pretty much have to do it old school by going after the really low level code.

In short, call the `SendInput` function of `user32.dll` by using `ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput`. Good luck with getting the parameters correct - I don't have the patience to figure it out for you.

[Here are the docs for the user32.dll SendInput API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Here is a helpful resource for figuring out the data types.](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/ctypes/wintypes.py) This is actually part of ctypes and can be imported by `import ctypes.wintypes` but I find it instructional to read the actual code.

So for example, to create a WORD with the value of the Virtual Key Code VK_RETURN, I think it would be

```
>>> ctypes.wintypes.WORD(0x0D)
c_ushort(13)
```

But there is a lot more you have to piece together from there. Just build up your parameters and call the function.

Last hint, use the examples in the second link for how to build "C" type structures. Then build one yourself using `ctypes.Structure`

Comment: You didn't say "easy" in your original question. LOL! This is much easier to do if you just install something. If you don't want to install anything, I'm having trouble thinking of other solutions. Maybe somebody else can. That said, this approach isn't hard, just tedious. If you've never done anything that low level, it would probably be worth the learning experience.

This highlights the value of using the right module for the right job though. The problem here is you don't want to install the right module.

Comment: That said, you could start tearing through some github code where people have solved this problem before and see what you find. However, I think you will find that most solutions leverage the C language at some point to actually talk to the API. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Use `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)`. `ctypes.windll` is an unreliable global that caches loaded libraries, which cache function pointers. It can cause problems when projects uses the same libraries. It also doesn't let you set `use_last_error=True` to use `ctypes.get_last_error()`, which is more reliable that using ctypes FFI to call `GetLastError()`.